# Reactjs - componentWillMount setState causes a state change on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.props.actions.A().then(result => {
        this.setState({ a: result });
    });
}
```

Now what is happening is that if i switch pages fast I receive the warning saying: `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting...`.

What can I do to prevent this scenario? (Obviously using the IsMounted property can solve it but as a read its obsolete)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. So it would be

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.actions.A().then(result => {
        this.setState({ a: result });
    });
}
```

Here is what FB said: 
"componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering."

Comment: Bad! The documents saying to use the componentWillMount

Comment: Can you send me the link to where you  read that? `componentDidMount` is used to set initial state of your component as well as getting data from an API. `componentWillMount` fires before `componentDidMount` and you are trying to set state in a component that is not mounted yet. That is why you are getting that error message.

Comment: Here is another thread talks about why it is not an anti-pattern to call `setState` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: There are many opposite posts on this subject, can't get a clear answer

Comment: I know because lot of people are confused about when to fetch data from a remote endpoint in React. `componentDidMount` is the place to do it and when your `Promise` resolves then you can set the state of your component to trigger a re-rendering.

Comment: I feel warning can be removed by not using setState in async callback, instead setting the data in a store that is passed into the component via props.